# EF5 doesn't create model correctly based on the existing database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have VS 2012 and the existing database (sql 2012).

In the database, there are one to one relationships and some columns are non-nullable with default value like " ". EDM generated the edmx diagram, but all the relationships are one to many.

I have `Customer` table with column `AddressReference1` as *not nullable* and its default value is " ". After generated entity class Customer, I deleted this property in .edmx designer, then I compile the project.

If I delete one of non-nullable property with default value of " " from the designer, the error was generated as following when I compiled the project.

> Error 1   Error 3023: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line
>   568:Column Customer.AddressReference1 in table Customer must be
>   mapped: It has no default value and is not nullable.
>     C:\Users\cliu\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\FulfillmentService\ShipmentModel.edmx   569 15  FulfillmentService

How do I solve this problem if I want to remove some properties from the entity class?

Comment: It's hard to help you without some specifics.

Comment: In my database, I have Customer table with column AddressReference1 as not nullable and its default value is " ". After generated entity class Customer, I deleted this property in .edmx designer, then I compile the project. I got the above error in my original post. The error says Customer.AddressReference1 has no default value, but database table defines the default for this column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete some properties from your model, you should delete them in your database to. Otherwise, EF conventions can't do their jobs correctly.

Usually, when you want full control over your model and its mappings, you should use Code-First approach.

Database-First approach depends heavily on EF conventions which dictate some limitations to developer because of their abstractions - Conventions!.

Although it is possible to change the db-first approach to code-first and remove some of those conventions by overriding `OnModelCreating` event, however this will cause to some strange problems which force you double-work only to fix them...!

In your current situation, you have no choice but accept one-to-many relations and keeping your model sync with your database.